# Как продлить символ в ячейке в таблице vba?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Как заполнить до конца строки символом '.' ?

Мой приблизительный код:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Cell(3, 2).Range = text + " " + String(200,".")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А никак. Конец строки - понятие весьма виртуальное. Можно добавлять по одной точке, пока количество строк в абзаце не увеличится, и последнюю из добавленных удалить. Но это разовое мероприятие - форматирование поплывёт даже просто от смены текущего принтера...

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 0. Идеальный вариант - это  в рантайме [вычислить длину строки](https://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum/index.php?PAGE_NAME=read&FID=8&TID=18963) с точками в текущем шрифте и скорректировать количество символов по ширине ячейки - [Свойство Range.ColumnWidth](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/excel.range.columnwidth).

Вариант 1. если шрифт не меняется, то можно добавить константу = ширина ячейки/максимальное количество точек, тогда при изменении ширины, можно всегда вычислить примерное количество точек для заполнения всей строки, отталкиваясь от того, сколько занимает места одна точка.

Вариант 2. можно попробовать обыграть через картинку, создать длинную картинку с точками и резать её по ширине ячейки. Но это самый бредовый вариант для Excel.

Comment: Для *Excel*? А вопрос по *Word* :)

Comment: Аналогично и по Word, получить ширину листа документа. Documents("Document1").PageSetup.PageWidth